# Informative Talend Logs with child job names and other information

Tags: etl, talend

I have talend Main job (trunjob) which calls another trunjob, which has 10 child ETL jobs inside it. When the main job executes, in the log (stdout) i'm only seeing the child job outputs which has a "tlogrow" component in them, I'm not seeing any other information like, which job has started, which job is running, which job has finished. which will be very useful while debugging and its available in most of the other ETL tools.

Example

```
< timestamp>: starting job <job name>   
.
.
< timestamp>: Finished job <job name>
```

Question:
 whether these information's will be available in Talend Administrator Console(TAC) in the Main job log? If not

Should I have to add a prejob and postjob to publish  these information's to develop a easily maintainable job? 
(or)
what is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can activate log4j logging with a log level of `info` or `debug` to have this information in your console or TAC logs. Go to File > Edit Project properties > log4j to activate it. Only downside is that you will have a verbose output including processed rows content.

Comment: Thanks for responding, as of now i'm using a free edition, when I click "File>Edit Properties>Log4j" i'm just seing an XML file, nothing else, Is this available only in enterprise edition, if possible can you paste a screen shot?

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to respond. You mentioned in your question Talend Administration Console, how come you're using the free version of the studio ? Sadly, log4j is an entreprise feature, and not available for the Open Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to activate `Stats & Logs` in the jobs tab. There it is possible to configure logging targets, which also includes files and the console.

This is very helpful for your purpose.

If this is only a commercial edition feature (which I don't know right now) then you might be able to get more information within your job with a `tPreJob -> tJava` and just use `System.out.println(job.name)` or something similar.